# Using NodeJS and ExpressJS to host a static Progressive Web App (PWA)

Tags: html, node.js, express, localhost, service-worker

I am trying to host a static Progressive Web App using ExpressJS, but since I'm fairly new to web dev I'm having some trouble.

I have found a number of great articles on how to use ExpressJS for routing (see links below), but none of them have helped me resolve my problem. These tutorials are quite basic and I can't find any tutorials which are more advanced - if you guys know of any please reply to this thread and link them!

```
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_express_framework.htm
https://stormpath.com/blog/build-nodejs-express-stormpath-app
https://zellwk.com/blog/crud-express-mongodb/
https://www.codementor.io/nodejs/tutorial/build-website-from-scratch-using-expressjs-and-bootstrap
```

My folder structure looks like this:

```
node_modules
package.json
server.js 
index.html
sw.js (service worker)
public/
    js/
        index.js
    style/
        index.css
```

and my server.js looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// Initialize static content
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/index.html', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
app.listen(8887);
```

In my index.html I am loading my public/style/index.css stylesheet and public/js/index.js javascript like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/style/index.css">
<script src="public/js/index.js"></script>
```

When I host my app using the command 'node server.js' and I navigate to http://localhost:8887/index.html, then I get served the correct index.html file but without the index.css file.

Here are my problems:

1. My style sheets aren't being served correctly (index.html renders
       without any css)
2. The browser is not picking up the service worker (sw.js)

---

Edit: Moving sw.js to the public/ folder causes an error when the service worker loads: GET http://localhost:8887/sw.js net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE.

Edit 2: More service worker errors: [image: More service worker errors]

Comment: remove 'public' from your script src and link href. Another things, isn't index.js missing? or you meant index.json?

Comment: Apologies, you're right - index.json was a typo on my part and was supposed to be index.js. Removing public from my scripts fix the script loading issue, but not the service-worker issue

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to register the express static like that:

```
var path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

and then, reference your scripts like that:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/index.css">
<script src="/js/index.js"></script>
```

What the service worker is doing?

Comment: Referencing my scripts like this "/style/index.css" without the /public/ worked, thanks! And my service worker is caching those resources (the css and javascript scripts), along with some push notification stuff. The service worker still isn't being picked up, though.

Comment: @Antag How do you boot the service worker? Possibly node foreman will help you: https://github.com/strongloop/node-foreman

Comment: service workers are a very new technology, and work very differently to other files. I may be wrong but I believe that the moment a service-worker supporting browser performs a request to ANY url, it will also request a service worker from that url's root domain. You can read up on service worker's [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers)

Comment: @Antag I understood something completely different. Sorry about that :)

Comment: no problem, I was actually completely wrong in my previous comment about how the browser loads service workers anyway (I think). But you helped me solve the problem, thanks Svabael!